# Requesting to remove question from ON HOLD status

Tags: discussion, status-completed

I have edited [this question of mine](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/86453/team-members-recommending-impractical-actions-during-audit) to address some of the comments such as HLGEM that this method of thinking is improper. I also clarified the timing to make it clear that this is taking place after the actual field work has completed, and during the report writing stage. Finally, I clarified the title to better clarify my question - how to take into account business needs when making recommendations.

**Can the question be removed from HOLD status?**

Comment: I was one of the original close votes.  Vote to reopen based on edits.